# Is it possible to use Matcap lighting in conjunction with normal maps?

Tags: matcaps

Is it possible to use MatCap lighting in conjunction with normal maps?

MatCap lighting works great when creating surface detail on sculpts etc. It would be nice if there was an easy way to also use MatCaps when examining normal map baking results.

Comment: You can [use matcaps to create normal maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwEXUN83LeI), it's not necessary it helps to examine baking results as it depends on what is meant by that

Comment: After baking I like to visually check over the results, look for any problems etc. MatCaps can provide nice high contrast lighting (depending on the matcap of course) which is why they're so convenient for sculpting, (as well as being cheap to compute). I was wondering if there was a shader or some other solution that would allow matcap lighting while displaying normal map information. Hope that makes sense? :)